# Assert that you hold an AWS IAM role to an external service

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-iam, identity

Is it possible for a service that has access to an IAM role to assert (prove) that it can access that role to an external service? Essentially, can an IAM role be used for external identity?

What I would like to do is have service X running inside AWS make an API call to an external service Y *not* running inside AWS saying "I am AWS identity `arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name`", and the external service would be able to verify this fact.

I realize this could be done by sending the actual access key / secret credentials to the external service, but I'm looking for a way to do this that doesn't involve sending live credentials.

Something like a signature/JWT that the external service could verify would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use STS service of AWS.

It will "create and provide trusted users with temporary security credentials that can control access to your AWS resources" base on the document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this isn't quite the right solution. I'm not looking for the external service to act as the role, and I'm specifically not wanting to share access keys as they would grant access to AWS resources. Instead I want the internal service to authenticate with the external service using an AWS identity. So like, "I prove I am role X", but that's it. Unless I'm missing something, STS lets you retrieve temporary access keys, but they are not restricted in any way.

Comment: Hi Jacob, at this time, i really don't know what you are trying to do, but I think STS can help you in this case. At any time you want to authenticate, use STS to retrieve the temporary keys and using them and they will expire after a period of time. 

Another AWS service for credentials is Cognito, you can take a quick look in that but I don't think it can help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The role gives access to AWS API via a signature but that requires that both ends know the secret access key which you obviously don't have.

You can use a solution that works by proving that the user has access to a verifiable resource. For example, you can give S3 putObject right to the role, make the bucket public, then the external service can ask the caller to put a certain file into this bucket. If the caller has access to the role then it can write the object, which then proves its access to the role.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`sts:GetCallerIdentity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) along with [AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) for this.

Here's how HashiCorp Vault seems to do it: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws#iam-auth-method

Here's how GCP seems to do it: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest/v1/TopLevel/token#body.request_body.FIELDS.subject_token (Search for "If subjectToken is for AWS")

Seems a bit involved but both GCP's and Vault's approach seems similar. If there's a better approach, I would love to know it.